# C counter for specific punctuations

Tags: c

So I succeeded in building other counters for letters and words, but now I  am stuck at this to count the sentence. My code is as below and when I run it it throws back a lot of error messages:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    //ask for user input
    char *text = get_string("Text: ");

 int sentence_counter = 0;

   for (int i = 0 ; text[i] ; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == "." || text[i] == "!" ||text[i] == "?"  )
        {
            sentence_counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("%i sentence(s)\n", sentence_counter);

}
```

I also tried the `if (strcmp(text[i], ".") == 0 )` based on previous similar problems, but it still doesn't work.

Where do I do wrong here? Thanks for the input!

edit: the program first asks the user to input a string of text (hence the get string command). It can be a short passage of text. The program then wants to count the number of sentences in the given text, by separating how many sentences end in ".", "?", or "!". Hope this helps.

Sorry if my questions seem stupid, I am still a newbie learning here and know absolutely nothing about C before. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Please update the question with test data. Input, expected output and the output your are getting.

Comment: `text[i]` is a `char`, you need to compare those to single-quoted characters (`'.'`, `'!'`, `'?'`). Double quotes designate a string. What is `get_string` doing?

Comment: Re "*it it throws back a lot of error messages*", uh, which ones?

Comment: Added some context above. The error messages look like this: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Werror,-Wstring-compare]

Comment: @yano, thanks a lot for this!  I didn't know that this is the case! Thanks again!

Comment: "it throws back a lot of error messages" Which? Quote them in full, verbatim and as text please.

Comment: The function: `get_string()` not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it does not contain a [mre] and when I googled the warning I found the answer instantly.

Comment: @klutt I did my research already and I guess I kind of missed the whole thing since the problematic happens at a lot of lines. Thought I shouldn't post the whole code because of academic honesty. Sorry for looking as if I wasn't doing my homework, though. It's my first experience in C and I guess I am a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are characters (char), double quotes are null-terminated strings (char *).

```
char c = 'x';
char *s = "Hello World";
```

> 'x' is an integer, representing the numerical value of the letter x in the machine’s character set
>    "x" is an array of characters, twocharacters long, consisting of ‘x’ followed by ‘\0’

**you have to use only Single quotes for your if condition like below**

```
for (int i = 0 ; text[i] ; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' ||text[i] == '?'  )
        {
            sentence_counter++;
        }
```